# JUnit: how to test a list of samples?

Tags: testing, junit

There was a clever way to provide a list of test-data to a JUnit test that tests a single method. E.g. I have the following test-data:

```
HashMap<InputParameterType,ExpectedResultType> testdata;

foreach (e : testdata) {
  assertEquals(methodUnderTest(e.getKey()),e.getValue())
}
```

This is available somehow, but I dont remember any keyword for google. Please help ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for paramaterized annotations 
http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/

http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/agile-development/test-driven-development/using-junit-parameterized-annotation/